# Protect ruby object attribute from being accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what is the best way to protect an attribute? See point below:

```
class Document

  # no method outside this class can access this directly. If they call document.data, error should be thrown. including in any rendering 
  field sensitive_data

  # but this method can be accessed by anyone
  def get_sensitive_data
    # where I apply the right protection
  end

end
```

Comment: I think  'protected' keyword do what you needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `protected` keyword.

```
class Document

  # but this method can be accessed by anyone
  def get_sensitive_data
    # where I apply the right protection
  end

  protected # or private if you don't want a child class accesses it (Thx @toch)

  # no method outside this class can access this directly. If they call document.data, error should be thrown. including in any rendering 
  field sensitive_data


end
```

Bear in mind that even if this just hides the getter / setter, anyone can retrieve the value using `send` for example.

Comment: or `private` if you don't want a child class accesses it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent someone from accessing that data.  Metaprogramming exposes pretty much all the internals of your class whether you want it to or not.

That said, marking get_sensitive_data as protected or private will at least prevent the get_sensitive_data method from being called accidentally.

Comment: thanks for this note. i ended up overriding access for object.sensitive_data by having a method of the same name, then protecting that instead.